# How do you reference a text field ID in a screen in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to use a function written in python to edit a text field in a screen in KivyMD. It works perfectly fine if the kivy code is not as part of a screen but once in a screen there seems to be a problem with the ids.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    AssignmentScreen:

<AssignmentScreen>:
    name: 'assignment'
    MDGridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
        rows: 6
        row_default_height: 125
        adaptive_height: True
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Assignment title"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Module"
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDTextField:
                id: pickedDates
                hint_text: "Deadline"
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: "Pick Date"
                on_press: app.show_date_picker()
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Estimated hours"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Assignment Weight (%)"
"""


class AssignmentScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(AssignmentScreen(name='assignment'))


class AssignmentTracker(MDApp):

    def show_theme_picker(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()

    def show_date_picker(self):
        MDDatePicker(self.set_date).open()

    def set_date(self, date_obj):
        self.root.ids.pickedDates.text = "test"
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

Window.size = (350, 700)
AssignmentTracker().run()
```

When the function set_date() is run it crashes with `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` as I can't figure out how to reference the MDTextField if it is inside the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `MDTextField` is in a different class

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker

Window.size = (350, 700)

screen_helper = """
Screen:
    ScreenManager:
        AssignmentScreen:
            id: assignment_scr

<AssignmentScreen>:
    name: 'assignment'
    MDGridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
        rows: 6
        row_default_height: 125
        adaptive_height: True
        
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Assignment title"
            
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Module"
            
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDTextField:
                id: pickedDates
                hint_text: "Deadline"
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: "Pick Date"
                on_press: app.show_date_picker()
                
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Estimated hours"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Assignment Weight (%)"
"""


class AssignmentScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(AssignmentScreen(name='assignment'))


class AssignmentTracker(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def show_theme_picker(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()

    def show_date_picker(self):
        MDDatePicker(self.set_date).open()

    def set_date(self, date_obj):
        self.root.ids.assignment_scr.ids.pickedDates.text = "test"


AssignmentTracker().run()
```